# Random number for given counts

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I am generating 4 digit random number by using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)`. Now I have another requirement. I have to get the number of random number to be generated in textbox. `eg: If they enter 5 in textbox it has to return 5 four-digit random number.` Any idea how to do it? any reference?

Comment: btw, you need `10000` as factor.

Comment: @NinaScholz that would make it a 5 digit number if 'Math.random()' returns 1

Comment: it never returns `1`, please see [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call your `4 digit random number generator function()` n time (n is given number in input field) as below:

```
for(let i=1;i<=this.n;i++) {
  this.ara.push(this.random());
}

random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(9999-1000) + 1000);
}
```

See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3de9d)  typescript implementation (Angular).

Answer (score 2):

Simply call the method a couple of times, depending on input. Note that you need to use below random number creation method instead of yours to guarantee 4 digit numbers.

```js
function getRand() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000) + 1000);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const length = document.getElementById('foo').value;
  const numbers = Array.from({length}, getRand); 
  
  document.getElementById('bar').innerText = numbers.join(', ');
});
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="number">
<button id="btn">Get</button>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Array.from({length}, getRand) is a awesome choice!

Comment: Awesome. Can anyone convert this to typescript format?

Comment: Sure. Do you want to pay with credit card or paypal? @FelixChristo

Answer (score 0):

Call getRandoms with n = 5, and high = 9999. Handle the 5-element return  array as you wish.

```
// pseudo-randomly generate an integer in the range low to high
function getRandom( high, low ) {
    // default low is 0
    if ('undefined' == typeof low) low = 0;
    var range = high - low + 1;
    var r = Math.floor( range*Math.random() + .5);
    return Math.min(low + r, high);
};

// get n pseudo-random number in the range low to high
function getRandoms( n, high, low ) {
    // default low is 0
    if ('undefined' == typeof low) low = 0;
    var randoms = new Array();    // initialize return
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randoms.push(getRandom(high, low));
    }
    return randoms;
};
```